# Why ACH is still slow even after 3 phases by nacha

Tags: united-states, banking, brokerage, ach

per [nacha](https://www.nacha.org/rules/same-day-ach-moving-payments-faster-phase-3) , USA banks are suppose to be processing [ACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACH_Network) fast, but I have not seen any improvement in ACH with either brokerage or bank accounts since year 2003.

What is the reason for no visible change in ACH fund transfer speed ?

or if any member has seen change in speed how quick ACH fund transfer?

Comment: In my experience, ACH transfers between "busy" pairs of accounts are *next day* (for example, transferring to or from my Ally savings and Chase checking accounts, a few times per month, where all transfers are initiated from Ally).  YMMV

Comment: Also note that for compliance reasons there is a minimum limit to how quickly processing can occur. In the UK at least it is intra day but many banks used to run compliance as a batch process at EOD and this may still be the case in the US.